# Recursive function that reverses subarray X[i,...,j]. Elements from index i to j inclusive

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, data-structures, reverse

So I am working on a textbook practice problem focusing on recursion which I'm half way there. I have come up with two functions that recursive copy the element in one array into another, but I am sort of stuck on my reverseArray3 function.

reverseArray3 should reverse the subarray X[i,...j] consisting of those elements from index i to index j inclusive. I know it should do this by swapping elements at position i and j then calling itself recursively on subarray X[i+1,...,j-1] from index i+1 and j-1.
I tried to look up question similar to mine, but no luck. Any help

```
class Recursion {

static void reverseArray1(int[] X, int n, int[] Y) {
    if(n < 1)
       return;
    Y[Y.length-n] = X[n-1];
    reverseArray1(X, n-1, Y);
}

static void reverseArray2(int[] X, int n, int[] Y) {
    if(n < 1)
      return;
    Y[n-1] = X[X.length-n];
    reverseArray2(X, n-1, Y);
}

static void reverseArray3(int[] X, int i, int j) {
//Where I'm stuck

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] A = {-1, 2, 3, 12, 9, 2, -5, -2, 8, 5, 7};
    int[] B = new int[A.length];
    int[] C = new int[A.length];

    for(int x: A) System.out.print(x+" ");
    System.out.println();

    reverseArray1(A, A.length, B);
    for(int x: B) System.out.print(x+" ");
    System.out.println();

    reverseArray2(A, A.length, C);
    for(int x: C) System.out.print(x+" ");
    System.out.println();

    reverseArray3(A, 0, A.length-1);
    for(int x: A) System.out.println(x+" ");
    System.out.println();
    }
}
```

below is how the output should look like:

```
1 2 6 12 9 2 -5 -2 8 5 7
7 5 8 -2 -5 2 9 12 6 2 -1 
7 5 8 -2 -5 2 9 12 6 2 -1  
7 5 8 -2 -5 2 9 12 6 2 -1
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest this:

```
static void reverseArray3(int[] X, int i, int j) {
    if(i>=j)
        return;
    int a=X[j];
    X[j]=X[i];
    X[i]=a;
    reverseArray3(X,i+1,j-1);
}
```

I hope it helps.